# Repository class returning null values in ViewModel to recycler view list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

Here is so far my implementation. I am trying to get the list of Bluetooth devices after the scan is finished. But the `observer` is not returning a list of devices.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_GPS = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 2;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

private MutableLiveData<List<DataModel>> deviceLiveData;
public static List<BleDevice> bleDeviceList;
private List<BleDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();

private RecyclerView rvDevices;
private MAdapter devicesAdapter;
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bleDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    rvDevices = findViewById(R.id.main_rv);

    BleManager.getInstance().init(getApplication());
    BleManager.getInstance()
            .enableLog(true)
            .setReConnectCount(5, 5000)
            .setConnectOverTime(20000)
            .setOperateTimeout(5000);
    checkPermissions();
}

private void checkPermissions() {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.please_open_blue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    List<String> permissionDeniedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            onPermissionGranted(permission);
        } else {
            permissionDeniedList.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (!permissionDeniedList.isEmpty()) {
        String[] deniedPermissions = permissionDeniedList.toArray(new String[permissionDeniedList.size()]);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, deniedPermissions, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
    }
}

Observer<List<BleDevice>> userListUpdateObserver = new Observer<List<BleDevice>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<BleDevice> userArrayList) {
        devicesAdapter = new MAdapter(MainActivity.this, userArrayList, new MAdapter.OnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        rvDevices.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        rvDevices.setAdapter(devicesAdapter);
        devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private void onPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    switch (permission) {
        case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !checkGPSIsOpen()) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Prompt")
                        .setMessage(R.string.gpsNotifyMsg)
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.setting,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_GPS);
                                    }
                                })

                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show();
            } else {
                startScan();

                mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(MainActivity.this).get(MainViewModel.class);
                mainViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(this, userListUpdateObserver);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private boolean checkGPSIsOpen() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager == null)
        return false;
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_GPS) {
        if (checkGPSIsOpen()) {
            startScan();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public final void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                             @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                             @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        onPermissionGranted(permissions[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public static void startScan() {
    BleManager.getInstance().scan(new BleScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanStarted(boolean success) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(BleDevice bleDevice) {
            super.onLeScan(bleDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanning(BleDevice bleDevice) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFinished(List<BleDevice> scanResultList) {
            bleDeviceList.addAll(scanResultList);
        }
    });
}

public static void clearScanDevice() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bleDeviceList.size(); i++) {
        BleDevice device = bleDeviceList.get(i);
        if (!BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(device)) {
            bleDeviceList.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

public void addDevice(BleDevice bleDevice) {
    removeDevice(bleDevice);
    String newBleDeviceName = bleDevice.getMac();
    if (newBleDeviceName == null) return;
}

public void removeDevice(BleDevice bleDevice) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bleDeviceList.size(); i++) {
        BleDevice device = bleDeviceList.get(i);
        if (bleDevice.getKey().equals(device.getKey())) {
            bleDeviceList.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder1.setTitle("Exit?");
    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to disconnect?.");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    BleManager.getInstance().disconnectAllDevice();
                    BleManager.getInstance().destroy();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });

    builder1.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    BleManager.getInstance().disconnectAllDevice();
    BleManager.getInstance().destroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void clearConnectedDevice() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bleDeviceList.size(); i++) {
        BleDevice device = bleDeviceList.get(i);
        if (BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(device)) {
            bleDeviceList.remove(i);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I have the `startScan()` method in `MainActivity.java`. There I can get the list of discoverable BleDevices in `onScanFinished()`. I am trying to implement the same method in the repository class **MainDataRepository.java**. I am getting `null` data from that class in **MainViewModel.java**. Here is my implementation of all classes.

**MainDataRepository.java**

```
public class MainDataRepository {
private static final String TAG = "MainDataRepository";
private static final MainDataRepository ourInstance = new MainDataRepository();

private MutableLiveData<List<BleDevice>> deviceListLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public static MainDataRepository getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}


public MutableLiveData<List<BleDevice>> getTodos() {
    BleManager.getInstance().scan(new BleScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanStarted(boolean success) {
            Log.d("View Model", "scAN started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(BleDevice bleDevice) {
            super.onLeScan(bleDevice);
            Log.d("onLeScan", "onLeScan: View Model");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanning(BleDevice bleDevice) {
            Log.d("View Model", "scannig");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFinished(List<BleDevice> scanResultList) {
            Log.d("View Model", "onScanFinished: " + scanResultList.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < scanResultList.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("View Model", "onScanFinished: " + scanResultList.get(i).getName() + " and " + scanResultList.get(i).getMac());
            }
        }
    });
    return deviceListLiveData;
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.java**

```
 public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<List<BleDevice>> userLiveData;
public static List<BleDevice> deviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private MainDataRepository repository = MainDataRepository.getInstance();

public MainViewModel() {
    super();
    userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    userLiveData = repository.getTodos();
    Log.d("View Model", "MainViewModel: " + userLiveData.getValue());
    init();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<BleDevice>> getUserMutableLiveData() {
    return userLiveData;
}

public void init() {
    populateList();
    userLiveData.setValue(deviceArrayList);
}

public void populateList() {
    deviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("Inside Populate", "populateList: ");
  }
}
```

**MAdapter.java**

```
public class MAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<BleDevice> bleDeviceList;
public OnClick click;

public MAdapter(Context mContext, List<BleDevice> bleDeviceList, OnClick click) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.bleDeviceList = bleDeviceList;
    this.click = click;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_ll, parent, false);
    return new MViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    BleDevice device = bleDeviceList.get(position);
    ((MViewHolder) holder).tvName.setText(device.getName());
    ((MViewHolder) holder).tvMac.setText(device.getMac());
    ((MViewHolder) holder).btnConnect.setText("Pair");

    ((MViewHolder) holder).btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click.onItemClick(v);
            ((MViewHolder) holder).btnConnect.setText("Paired");
            ((MViewHolder) holder).btnConnect.setClickable(false);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bleDeviceList.size();
}

static class MViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvName, tvMac;
    private Button btnConnect;

    public MViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        tvMac = itemView.findViewById(R.id.device_mac_address);
        btnConnect = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    }
}

public interface OnClick {
    public void onItemClick(View v);
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.